# How to only have 1 query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I created 3 queries in SQL Server, I just want to know if I can have 1 query instead of these 3 queries?

These are my 3 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(JONumber) JANUARY
FROM JobOrders
WHERE JODate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/31/2017'

SELECT COUNT(JONumber) FEBRUARY
FROM JobOrders
WHERE JODate BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND '02/28/2017'

SELECT COUNT(JONumber) TOTAL
FROM JobOrders
WHERE JODate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '02/28/2017'
```

Comment: what you want in result? one return output or 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without knowing your specific flavor of SQL, I can offer the following single query which uses conditional aggregation to arrive at the same results:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN JODate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS JanCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN JODate BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-28'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FebCount,
       COUNT(*) AS TotalCount
FROM JobOrders
```

Since you are using SQL Server, a better approach would be to `GROUP BY` the month (and year), and let the database worry about counting records:

```
SELECT CAST(MONTH(JODate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' +
       CAST(YEAR(JODate) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS MonthYear,
       COUNT(*) AS numOrders
FROM JobOrders
WHERE JODate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-02-28'
GROUP BY CAST(MONTH(JODate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(JODate) AS VARCHAR(4))
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: There's a Total result for the whole date range in the example SQL, so add a `ROLLUP` onto the GROUP BY to produce this row.

Answer (score 0):

If you need 3 row you can use union

```
    SELECT 1 as seq, JANUARY, COUNT(JONumber) 
    FROM JobOrders
    WHERE JODate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/31/2017'
    UNION 
    SELECT 2, FEBRUARY, COUNT(JONumber) FEBRUARY
    FROM JobOrders
    WHERE JODate BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND '02/28/2017'
    UNION
    SELECT  100, TOTAL, COUNT(JONumber) 
    FROM JobOrders
    WHERE JODate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '02/28/2017'
    order by seq
```

otherwise you can use @TimBiegeleisen answer

Answer (score 0):

Use TEMP table and INSERT all 3 SELECT queries :

```
 CREATE TABLE #Table (Column1 VARCHAR(100)

 INSERT INTO #Table( Column1) 
 SELECT COUNT(JONumber) JANUARY
 FROM JobOrders
 WHERE JODate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '01/31/2017'

 INSERT INTO #Table( Column1) 
 SELECT COUNT(JONumber) FEBRUARY
 FROM JobOrders
 WHERE JODate BETWEEN '02/01/2017' AND '02/28/2017'

 INSERT INTO #Table( Column1) 
 SELECT COUNT(JONumber) TOTAL
 FROM JobOrders
 WHERE JODate BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '02/28/2017' 

  SELECT * FROM #Table
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want 1 table with three columns, you could try going down this pathway: group by month, year, and then pivot into month columns...

```
    select pvt.* from 
    (
    select  DatePart(year,JODate) [year],
    DateName(month,JODate) [month],
    count(JONumber) [JobCount] from JobOrders
    group by DatePart(year,JODate), DateName(month,JODate)
    )results
    Pivot( max(JobCount) for month in(January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December))pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the data are from the same table, I recomend to do this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN JODate>='2017-01-01' AND JODate<='2017-01-31' THEN COUNT(JONumber) END AS JANUARY,
    CASE WHEN JODate>='2017-02-01' AND JODate<='2017-02-28' THEN COUNT(JONumber) END AS FEBRUARY,
    COUNT(JONumber) AS TOTAL
FROM JobOrders
```